# How to add Relative References Paths in Visual C#

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I add a dataaccess.dll, i included this dll in my proyect, but the problem is that .net add the whole dir from that dll.

```
c:/users/myuser/documents/dataaccess.dll
```

The problem is when i change to another computer, it can not find that dll, because the path doesn exists.

> I can make 2 things for solve this problem, add all dll to C: and
>   reference to C:/dataaccess.dll
>   or 
>   Add dynamically path to the dataaccess.dll

I would like to know if there is another way, for example create a lib folder inside my project and configure .net to search dll, inside that folder without reference that folder with the whole path.

Comment: Start by editing your title to be in Sentence Case.

Answer (score 1):

Don't refer to a hard coded path like this - `c:/users/myuser/documents/dataaccess.dll` instead have a library folder added in your solution folder. And give a relative path something like - `..\lib\dataaccess.dll`.

`..` will take one folder above the current project location. `lib` is the folder in which the dll is present. You can check this by editing the .csproj file in a notepad and seeing what reference it makes. And then replace `c:/users/myuser/documents/dataaccess.dll` with the text `..\lib\dataaccess.dll`

Answer (score 1):

Find your DLL reference, open properties and set it to Copy Local - Always. This will make a copy of it which will not depend on the source

Comment: I think this does it automatically now but good tip to look for. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` will give the path that your `.exe` is located at. To get the directory the `.exe` is in, you can use `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`

You could use that to always have a reference to the `.exe` location, and alter it to get to the .`dll` accordingly.